# MEAN Application Update Function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to write a MEAN application update function but the update will not save to the MongoDB database. I am trying to update the title of my document only. Below is the function I have written.

```
router.updateJob = function (req, res) {

    Job.findById(req.params.id, function(err, job) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        else {

            var oldTitle = job.title;
            var newTitle = req.body.title;

            job.save(function (err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                else
                    job.title = newTitle;
                    res.json({updatedTitle: job.title});
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I am sending the new title in a JSON string using the Web Storm API testing tool. The string I am sending looks like the one below:

```
{"title" : "Updated Title"}
```

The response I am getting from the API is shown below, you can see that the title is showing as Updated Title. But when I go into the database it is showing as the original title which is Test.

```
{"updatedTitle":"Updated Title"}
```

What do I have to do to get the new title to save to the database? If there is any other information you need to help figure this out please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `findByIdAndUpdate` method. So:

```
router.updateJob = function (req,res) {
  Job.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new:true}, function(err, doc) {
     if(err)
         return res.json(err);
     else
         return res.json(doc);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually job.save(callback). Assignment should be done before the .save()

```
router.updateJob = function (req, res) {

Job.findById(req.params.id, function(err, job) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    else {
        var newTitle = req.body.title;

        job.title = newTitle;

        job.save(function (err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            else
                res.json({updatedTitle: job.title});
        });
    }
 });
};
```